# css html - DIV and img doesn't display on Firefox, wrong position on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I added a loading gif to cover my iframe while it loads, and then disappear when it does load. It works great, however on firefox the loading gif simply isnt there and on safari, its displayed way off to the right.

```
        #loodImg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
    #loodImg img {
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-left: 4%
    }
    #loodImg img {
        display: table;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-left: 4%
    }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    #loodImg img {
        min-width: 70%;
        min-height: 70%;
        margin-left: 130%
    }
    #loodImg img {
        display: table;
        min-width: 70%;
        min-height: 70%;
        margin-left: 130%
    }
}
```

Here's HTML

```
<div id="loodImg">
   <div><img src="http://WEBSITELINKHERE/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Loader-Icon.gif" /></div>
</div>
<iframe border=0 name=iframe src="/virtualtour.htm" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" onload="document.getElementById('loodImg').style.display='none';"></iframe>
```

Any improvements and fixes you can assist me with making this better will help. Thanks. Please note it works flawlessly on Chrome.

Comment: display:table, margin-left 130%? why you do this?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh

Answer (score 0):

please clarify: 
i tested this code with some giphy links as placeholders and it seems to work in firefox and safari.
maybe the iframe just loads to fast?

```css
      #loodImg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
@media screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
    #loodImg img {
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-left: 4%
    }
    #loodImg img {
        display: table;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-left: 4%
    }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    #loodImg img {
        min-width: 70%;
        min-height: 70%;
        margin-left: 130%
    }
    #loodImg img {
        display: table;
        min-width: 70%;
        min-height: 70%;
        margin-left: 130%
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="loodImg">
   <div><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7bukj6aXZuPqibpm/giphy.gif" /></div>
</div>
<iframe border=0 name=iframe src="https://giphy.com/gifs/bobs-burgers-funny-comedy-3ohzdEbR1FaSkFgp6o/links" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" onload="document.getElementById('loodImg').style.display='none';"></iframe>
```

Comment: This does not work sadly. I added :before to each div img and that displayed the imgs on firefox, but the positions were wrong. Strange. Loading img does not display still.                                                                            EDIT: I added the image you used as the loading gif and it DID show on firefox, however way off the the right and barely in view.  Chrome - http://prntscr.com/fmphoi Firefox - http://prntscr.com/fmphtc

Comment: did you inspect them with your dev-tools? try removing that left-margin : 130